# having trouble with range type

Tags: python, range

the second part of the code it's supposed to get the index(even)and then multiply it by the length of the string. after that, it should replace the word in the list with the result of the operation and print something like
original list: ['computer', 'science', 'university', 'alberta', 'edmonton']
modified list: [0, 'science', 20, 'alberta', 32]

```
lista = []
word = input('Enter a word >')
while word != 'stop':
    lista.append(word)
    word = input('Enter a word >')
print(lista)

for index in range(0, len(lista), 2):
    lista[index] = index
    index *= len(str(word))
    print(lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You have two problems.

One, you are using the variable `word` in the `for` loop which is not updated on each iteration. As your code currently stands, `word` will only ever store the last word that is appended to the list (in your case, 'edmonton'). You need to update the variable on each iteration. I'd recommend not using `word` for readability as you used it in the `while` loop for a different purpose (I used `tmp_word` instead):

```
for index in range(0, len(lista), 2):
    tmp_word = lista[index]
    lista[index] = index
    index *= len(str(tmp_word))

print(lista)
```

What we did is just store the string at the `index` position in a variable, `tmp_word`.

If we run the code, we get:

```
[0, 'science', 2, 'alberta', 4]
```

This is our second problem - can you figure out why the numbers in the list are not correct? If you can't figure out a solution, let me know and we'll work through it!

Answer (score 0):

There is a small logical mistake in your code you're first updating the list item with the **item index** and then you're modifying the index

**Correct code**

```
lista = []
word = input('Enter a word >')
while word != 'stop':
    lista.append(word)
    word = input('Enter a word >')

for index in range(0, len(lista), 2):
    word = lista[index]
    temp = index*len(word)
    lista[index] = temp

print(lista)
```

**My implementation will look like**

```py
for index in range(0, len(lista), 2):
    lista[index] = index * len(lista[index])
```

**Using List comprehension**

```py
lista = [i*len(lista[i]) if i % 2 == 0 else lista[i] for i in range(len(lista))]
```